# Convert JUnit test case to Selenium IDE html file?

Tags: selenium, webdriver, selenium-rc, selenium-ide

I have learnt how to export Selenium IDE html file to JUnit.

But if I make a change to the JUnit test - is there a way I can convert the Junit test to Selenium IDE html file so that even if I run the test from IDE the new change is recorded?

What is the best practice for such scenarios?

Note: (2nd user#Manii88), I am also facing the same issue...THough it might be an old question, it is still not solved yet...I find this question compelling because, say for example, I am in middle of some test, which i have exported from selenium ide and modified in Selenium Webdriver, eclipse, to check the viability of test cases and handling of popups...then, i want to continue my test case in ide...till the step completed, i want to proceed quickly and then, the next step, i will continue recording...

Hope this makes the scenario clear...Any answers???

Thanks!

Comment: what kind of change would you make ?

Answer (score 0):

Though it's not always possible, you may try the below steps to achieve it to some extent:

1. Install the latest *Selenium IDE* (or at least >= *1.6*)
2. Open *Selenium IDE*
3. `Options` Menu > `Format` > `JUnit 4 (Webdriver backed)` [or use the *same* option here which was used while exporting html to JUnit]
4. Dismiss the warning dialog
5. Go to the `Source` tab, and paste your JUnit code
6. Change the format again back to HTML by selecting `Options` > `Format` > `HTML`
7. Dismiss the warning dialog
8. Switch (back) to `Table` tab to see your latest changes